# Enable post function from url php

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have a post form, where you post your name, text, place and contact. 4 labels.

The code for the post form in html looks like this:

```
<div  class="form">
            <form id="contactform" action="post.php" method="post"> 
                <p class="contact"><label for="who">Who</label></p> 
                <input id="who" name="who" placeholder="Who are you? (First & Second name)" required="" type="text"> 

                <p class="contact"><label for="email">Text</label></p> 
                <input id="what" name="what" placeholder="Text" required="" type="text"> 

                <p class="contact"><label for="username">Where</label></p> 
                <input id="where" name="where" placeholder="Country, City, Street..." required="" type="text"> 

                <p class="contact"><label for="password">Contact</label></p> 
                <input type="text" id="contact" name="contact" placeholder="Phone number or email"required=""> 
<input class="buttom" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Submit" type="submit">
```

And the post.php code looks like this:

```
<?php header("Location: feed.php"); ?>
<?php 

define ( 'DB_NAME','database_name');
define ( 'DB_USER','user');
define ( 'DB_PASSWORD','foot');
define ( 'DB_HOST','localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!link) {
die('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$value1 = $_POST['who'];
$value2 = $_POST['text'];
$value3 = $_POST['where'];
$value4 = $_POST['contact'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO content (`who`, `text`, `where`, `contact`) VALUES ('$value1', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4')";


 if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
    echo "You've just posted your text!";
mysql_close();
?>
```

What I want is that you should be able to post a text by writing, for example, www.mywebsite.com/post.php?name=MyName&text=MyText&place=MyPlace&contact=Contact

So you should be able to fill in your form through the url.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change all your $_POST to $_GET or $_REQUEST and you are done.

$_GET: [http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)
$_REQUEST: [http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: Why use $_REQUEST instead of $_GET?